# how to copy the latest file from local machine to server using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi everyone i have used this code to generate backup file, find out latest file in the directory and copy that latest file to server using ip.the problem is,it is not copying the latest file to server.how to do this?

here is the code i have used:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#Defines our output file

OUTPUTDIR=/home/backup
OUTPUT=$OUTPUTDIR/backup-of-$(date +%d-%m-%Y).zip
BACKUPDIR="/home/user/Desktop/backup/"
LATESTFILE=ls -t1 | head -n1

#Display message about starting the backup
echo "Starting backup of directory $BACKUPDIR to file $OUTPUT"

#Start the backup
zip -r $OUTPUT $BACKUPDIR

#Checking the status of the last process:
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
#Display confirmation message
echo "The file:"
echo $OUTPUT
echo "was created as a backup"
else
#Display error message message
echo "There was a problem creating:"
echo $OUTPUT
echo "as a backup for:"
echo $BACKUPDIR
fi
echo "Please Enter The IP to save backup file"
read ip
echo "Connecting to" $ip. please wait...
scp $LATESTFILE user@$ip:/home/user/Desktop
```

Comment: IMO this is the real question being asked, not the question that we've marked this as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to enclose the command that gets the last file:

```
LATESTFILE=$(ls -t1 | head -n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd change the following line

```
LATESTFILE=ls -t1 | head -n1
```

to

```
LATESTFILE=`ls -t1 $OUTPUTDIR | head -n1`
```

and move that line to just before requesting the IP.

The "`" signifies to execute what is between the "`" characters and return the results. If you left that line on top you wouldn't get the lastest file in the directory because it hasn't been created. You also was doing an "ls" on the current directory and shouldn't it be on the directory where your backup files are written to?

also need to change the line

```
scp $LATESTFILE user@$ip:/home/user/Desktop
```

to

```
scp $OUTPUTDIR/$LATESTFILE user@$ip:/home/user/Desktop
```

Hope this helps